# Configure Table cell in model class

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to show data in UITablleView after getting it from http request. I heard that the best and professional way to do it is configure the cell and do the call request in model class then send it to the view controller. So here is what I tried to do but I think it's not going well. I know this is a wrong wy but I wanted to show you what I got based on someone.

**UITable View Cell :**

```
@IBOutlet weak var status : UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var date : UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var model : UILabel!

func ConfigCell (car : Car){    
    let urlstr = "http://localhost:8000/api/newuser/check"
    let url = URL(string: urlstr)
    guard let token = UserDataSingleton.sharedDataContainer.token else { return  }
    let headers = ["Authorization":"Bearer \(token)"]
    var statusCode: Int = 0
    request(url! ,  method: .get,  encoding: JSONEncoding.prettyPrinted ,  headers: headers )
        .responseJSON { response in
            if let value: AnyObject = response.result.value as AnyObject? {
                //Handle the results as JSON
                let json = JSON(value)                  
                for (key, subJson) in json["allcar"] {
                    if let status = subJson["status"].string {
                        self.status.text = status
                        if let date = subJson["created_at"].string {
                              self.date.text = date

                            if let model = subJson["model"].string {
                                self.model.text = model
                                let Status = [
                                    Car(model: model, status: status, date: date)]
```

**Car model**

```
 class Car {

private var _mode : String?
private var _status : String?
private var _date : String?


var model : String{
    return _model!
}
var status : String {
    return _status!
}
var date : String {
    return _date!
}

init(model : String , status :String,date : String) {
    self._status = status
    self._model = model
    self._date = date
}
```

**Controller**

```
class testViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource {

 let data = [Car]()

@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    tableview.delegate = self
    tableview.dataSource = self
    print(data.count)
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
   return 1
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return data.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CarCell", for: indexPath) as! CarC

    let entry = data[indexPath.row]
    cell.date.text = entry.date
    cell.model.text = entry.model
    cell.status.text = entry.status
    return cell
```

I could do all in the view controller and cell labels in a different model but I'm seeking the "professional" way of doing this
**problem with this code**

The data array is 0 so there's no data showing in the table

Comment: This question might be better suited for the Code Review site (http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: thanks I'll do that :)

Comment: Taking a quick look, it looks fine to me.  Which part is not going well?  Missing the closed bracket at the end?  Hmm...  You are not creating a model object by instantiating Car, actually.

Comment: the car array is 0 `let data = [Car]()` which means there is no data showing when I run the app